# Dereferencing string iterator won't compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors, iterator

I have a problem where example code will compile and run in the Code Blocks environment but will not compile in visual studio 2012

```
list<string> names;
names.push_back("Mary");
names.push_back("Zach");
names.push_back("Elizabeth");
list<string>::iterator iter = names.begin();
while (iter != names.end()) {
    cout << *iter << endl;  // This dereference causes compile error C2679
    ++iter;
}
```

Results in the following compiler error

```
1>chapter_a0602.cpp(20): error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a
right-hand operand of type 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' (or there is no
acceptable conversion)
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
```

when I change the list of strings to a list of ints the code compiles and runs in VS2012.

when I also change the dereference to the following it compiles

```
cout << *the_iter->c_str() << endl;
```

However I have two other dereference problems further down the code

```
cout << "first item: " << names.front() << endl;
cout << "last item: "  << names.back() << endl;
```

I really don't understand why these errors are compiler dependant.

sorry about the formatting but I couldn't get it to accept the code.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following include directive:

```
#include <string>
```

as that is where [`operator<<(std::ostream&, std::string&)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) is defined.

Note [VS2012 supports the range-based for statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj203382.aspx), which would transform the outputting loop to:

```
for (auto const& name: names) std::cout << name << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`ostream operator<<(ostream& os, const string& str)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) is defined in the `string` header.

You probably just forgot to include it to have this kind of error.

You should just include it at the top of your file :

```
#include <string>
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/XNwICv).